# Local Storage may be conflicting with Toggle Slow

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to have .child_box class to open and close slow but seems Local Storage is not respecting it. Either it wont open or it wont close. Without Local Storage, it works fine. Stumped.

The js:

```
  $("document").ready(function () {
    $(".manualclose").click(function () {
      $(".child_box").toggle();
    });

    ls = localStorage.getItem('on')
    if(ls) {
      $(".child_box").show("slow")
    }

    $(".open_child").click(function () {
      localStorage.setItem('on',true)
      toggled = $(".child_box").toggle();
      if(toggled.is(":hidden")) {
        localStorage.clear();
      }
  });

    $(".manualclose").click(function() {
      localStorage.clear();
      $(".child_box").hide("slow") 
    });
  });
```

The button:

```
<div class="open_child" title="', $txt['sub_boards2'], '">
  <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: you got some errors in the console?

Comment: Nothing in the console.

Comment: Just noticed that when you open the class and refresh the page, it opens slow. But the trick supposed to open and close slow after click. Not when refresh the page.

Comment: If I add "slow" in this line: toggled = $(".child_box").toggle("slow"); It works as it should but Local Storage doesn't remember last click.

Comment: and if you get the values over the console from localStorage you get the right values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage` isn't conflicting with `toggle()`. The problem is down to the way the browser schedules a reflow whilst executing JavaScript.

In this event handler

```
        $(".open_child").click(function(){
            localStorage.setItem('on',true)
            toggled = $(".child_box").toggle(500);
            if(toggled.is(":hidden")){
                localStorage.clear();
            }
        });
```

your code toggles the `.child-box` element. It immediately goes to see if that element is now hidden.

The browser is running the animation that is caused by `.toggle()` and carries on executing the JavaScript. It checks whether the element is hidden, which it isn't because the animation hasn't completed yet, and so doesn't clear the `localStorage`. Only later when the animation completes would the element appear as 'hidden'.

You need to do things in a different order:

```
        $(".open_child").click(function(){
            let hidden =$(".child_box").is(":hidden");
            if (hidden) {
                $(".child_box").show(500);
                localStorage.setItem('on',true)
            } else {
                $(".child_box").hide(500);
                localStorage.removeItem('on');
            }
        });
```

This version checks the `hidden` status first, then shows or hides the element as required, and updates `localStorage` to match.

There is an alternative approach: use the `complete` function available to the jQuery `.toggle()` method to update `localStorage`. You'd still need to check to see what `.toggle()` has just done, so you don't gain much.

FWIW, I never use `.toggle()` precisely because I don't know what action it's performing.

A couple of other thoughts:

- You're not declaring the variable you use, so they're being placed in the global context. This is a bad idea. Declare them in the functions they're used in with `let`.
- `localStorage` stores strings, not other data type. JavaScript has coerced the data for you so you've got away with it, but good practice suggests that you should be more rigorous.
- Using `localStorage.clear()` precludes the use of `localStorage` for any other purpose. Use `localStorage.removeItem()` instead.

Comment: Amazing. This works. I now see the difference in the order. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's localStorage. what i noticed:

a) you don't declare the variable ls.

b) why are you using a div as a button?

c) you don't use parse and stringify to get and set values in the localStorage.

d) you put a title in a DIV container

f) the title you set looks like PHP. it is missing the < ?php echo $text ... ;? > Tags

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes, it is part of php. Issue is resolved.